# Moving a LAMP set up from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: 10.10, 64-bit, webserver

I have setup an Ubuntu server 10.10 32bit on an old Dell D610 Laptop for testing.
I have the latest PHP, MySQL and Apache with Wordpress installed.

After the testing is over and once I finish adding material to my wordpress I will build 
a Ubuntu 10.10 64bit VM on Hyper-V.

What I am wondering is , if it's best practice to build everything from scratch (which will take me more time and would like to avoid)

or transfer the database and all other settings?
If I choose to transfer how and what I need to do?

Here's where I'd like some help as I am still an intermediate admin (If I can call it that!)

I am looking forward for your help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can generally transfer settings in ASCII files (most stuff under `/etc`, PHP/Source code and such), as it not inherently dependent on the [Instruction Set Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) (ISA).

Databases are a wholly different thing, however. They usually pack things in machine-dependent ways in order to optimize things. So your 'raw' db-files cannot likely be moved freely, though you may get lucky (I don't know about MySQL in particular). You can, however, do a dump of your database into SQL statements, thus transforming it into ACSII data, which is ISA-neutral.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the binary 64-bit version of the Mysql, Apache-httpd and PHP.
There will be no differences in your SQL dump or in your PHP scripts between the two systems.

Just stick with the same major versions and check for the PHP (php.ini) and httpd settings.

Comment: Thanks for that!!!What about the static IP on the server and all the references.
Do I have to change everything manually?

Comment: For changing the IP and other stuff, I would use a Perl one liner such as: perl -pi.orig -e 's/192\.168\.0\.10/192\.168\.0\.11/g' /etc/network/interfaces. You could use this to replace any old values with new ones.